# how to change :nth element background size

Tags: html, css

How can I change the size of the pictures in this example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IDKAo I am making a photo gallery with this effect, and I need to change the size of the pictures, can anyone help? It is a pretty complex css so I understand if you can't.
[image: This is my desired image]

Comment: i saw your provided link and can you show me your desired result pic also what exactly do you need....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the existing code

```
.icon {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/1);
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;  
}
```

In the place of height and width specify the value us like for example :

```
 height:80px;
 width:80px;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change it's size in .icon class. now it is 50*50 ... the pictures are in a list ( < ul > < li > < /li >< li >< /li >< /ul >) if u change pictures size you should change the width of the .container class too. ... you can find the css codes in chrome just by pressing f12 as shown in the picture ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/1);
  display:inline-block;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;  
}
```

check this to increase the size of the image